# Remote overwrite crontab file with sudo

Tags: shell-script, ssh, sudo, cron, io-redirection

I'm trying to build a script that automatically takes a file on the remote server and replace with crontab file, but I get permission denied.

My idea is to create a shell function for it:

```
update_crontab() {
  SSH_HOST=$1
  FOLDER=$2

  {
    if ssh -o "BatchMode yes" $SSH_SUDO_WHITOUT_PASS@$SSH_HOST "[ -f $FOLDER/crontab ]"
    then
      # Folder exists replace crontab with new file
      ssh -o "BatchMode yes" $SSH_SUDO_WHITOUT_PASS@$SSH_HOST "sudo cat $FOLDER/crontab > /etc/crontab"
      echo "crontab overwirte from $FOLDER/crontab"
    fi
  } || {
    echo "Error - Folder not exists"
    exit 1
  }
}
```

Comment: consider using `scp` instead?

Comment: how can i use scp local between 2 files? my new file is local on the remote server, and i need to replace the remote servers crontab file, not from my machine to remote server.

Comment: maybe I misunderstood; you're trying to copy the remote system's $FOLDER/crontab over the remote system's /etc/crontab? no "local" files involved at all?

Comment: yes currect, have the file on my remote server.

Comment: @Rui, you took the only "question" out of their question. Perhaps leave them with their actual question, if you're going to go to the effort of removing it?

Comment: @JeffSchaller My mistake, yes did not intended to cut all that, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both files are remote, you can simply:

```
  ssh ... "sudo cp $FOLDER/crontab /etc/crontab"
```

... which avoids the "sudo redirection" problem where only the `cat` has elevated privileges, and your normal user shell does the `> /etc/crontab` redirection.

Comment: Thanks so much, so simple and i have not thinking about it.